# Rapidly instantiate objects - good or bad?

Tags: c++, oop

**Note:** *Although this question doesn't directly correlate to games, I've molded the context around game development in order to better visualize a scenario where this question is relevant.*

**tl;dr:** Is rapidly creating objects of the same class memory intensive, inefficient, or is it common practice?

Say we have a "bullet" class - and an instance of said class is created every time the player  'shoots' - anywhere between 1 and 10 times every second. These instances may be destroyed (obviously) upon collision.

Would this be a terrible idea? Is general OOP okay here (i.e.: `class Bullet { short x; short y; }`, etc.) or is there a better way to do this? Is `new` and `delete` preferred?

Any input much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of approaches. Allocation on stack is faster than on heap and if you need heep, you can use `std::vector::reserve`

Comment: That depends entirely on *how* you instantiate them...

Comment: What would be the best way, @delnan?

Comment: That depends how you use them, what you need and what trade offs you can make... ;-) Really, there is not a single best way. I fear this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good use-case for techniques like [memory-pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) or [Free-Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list). The idea in both is that you have memory for a certain number of elements pre-allocated. You can override the `new` operator of your class to use the pool/list or use `placement new` to instantiate your class in a retrieved address.

The advantages:

- no memory fragmentation
- pretty quick

The disadvantages:

- you must know the maximum number of elements beforehand

Comment: Would this be as, more, or less effective than using stack?

Comment: What do you mean by "using stack"?

Comment: @Adosi Difficult to answer. Automatic storage duration (which you presumably mean by "stack") allows many more optimizations, such as splitting the object into registers (if it's small enough and you don't take its address and some other conditions are met). On the other hand, allocation in a properly designed pool/free list is virtually as cheap as allocating stack memory, and the memory is also likely to be in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just constantly create and delete objects.  Instead, an alternative is to have a constant, resizable array or list of object instances that you can reuse.  For example, create an array of 100 bullets, they don't all have to be drawn, have a `boolean` that states whether they are "active" or not.

Then whenever you need a new bullet, "activate" an inactive bullet and set its position where you need it.  Then whenever it is off screen, you can mark it inactive again and not have to delete it.

If you ever need **more** than 100 bullets, just expand the array.

Consider reading this article to learn more: [Object Pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html).  It also has several other game pattern related topics.

Comment: In most implementations of this, you are effectively instantiating an object when you "active" one. You don't *allocate memory*, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @delnan No, what I mean to say is that you can lazy initialize the first 100 if you want, or actively initiate them if you want the cost to be up front.  But whenever you are done with them, don't remove them, just blank their values (or just mark them inactive for the renderer) and whenever you need a new object after you have run out of empty bullets, reset the paramters of whatever the oldest inactive bullet is (or whatever your reactivation scheme is).  This also helps with fragmentation as well.

Comment: @zero298 I know fully well what you mean. But "reset the parameter" is effectively a constructor call (in fact, many pool implementations do just that, they call the destructor when dropping an object and call placement `new` when asked for a new object). You just saved yourself an allocation.

Comment: @delnan Ah, I did not know that.  Thanks.  Do you have any articles that I could read more about that?

Comment: @zero298 I don't have a good source for pools specifically, but DICE's [ScopeStack](http://dice.se/wp-content/uploads/scopestacks_public.pdf) is related and astonishingly clever.

Answer (score 2):

The very very least that happens when you allocate an object is a function call (its constructor). If that allocation is dynamic, there is also the cost of memory management which at some point could get drastic due to fragmentation.

Would calling some function 10 times a second be really bad? No. Would creating and destroying many small objects dynamically 10 times a second be bad? Possibly. Should you be doing this? Absolutely not.

Even if the performance penalty is not "felt", it's not ok to have a suboptimal solution while an optimal one is immediately available.

So, instead of for example a `std::list` of objects that are dynamically added and removed, you can simply have a `std::vector` of bullets where addition of bullets means appending to the vector (which after it has reached a large enough size, shouldn't require any memory allocation anymore) and deleting means swapping the element being deleted with the last element and popping it from the vector (effectively just reducing the vector size variable).

Comment: This sounds very practical. Thank you!

Comment: Note that sometimes constructors can be inlined. There are also much better ways of re-using space for deleted bullets (swap-and-pop for example avoids the linear search on creation).

Comment: @delnan, true. I'll switch to that one.

Answer (score 1):

Think that with every instantiation there is a place in the heap where it need to allocate memory and create a new instance. This may affect the performance. Try using collection and create an instance of that collection with how many bullets you want.

Comment: Only if you take "instantiate" to mean "call to `new Bullet`", which is far from the only way one can create objects.